# Marker Clustering Not Showing using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker, markerclusterer

I have copied this code from the google map API documentation ([Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps)). the markers are showing but I cant get the Marker Clustering to work.

I have 1000s of markers and the example google has given looks like its just for couple of markers. My map is too full of markers making it difficult to click on the correct ones.

I have copied the example into fiddle. The API key is not set but the code is the same in my project.

```js
var customLabel = {
        restaurant: {
          label: 'R'
        },
        bar: {
          label: 'B'
        }
      };

        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.863276, 151.207977),
          zoom: 12
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/mapmarkers2.xml', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);                     infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }
      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }
      function doNothing() {}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
    </script>
 <div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me if I add the markerclusterer to that example

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/grwqdka7/)

[image]

**updated code snippet:**

```js
var customLabel = {
  restaurant: {
    label: 'R'
  },
  bar: {
    label: 'B'
  }
};

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.863276, 151.207977),
    zoom: 12
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
  downloadUrl('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/mapmarkers2.xml', function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
      imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
    });
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
      var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
      var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
      var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
      var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')), parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
      var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
      var strong = document.createElement('strong');
      strong.textContent = name
      infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
      infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
      var text = document.createElement('text');
      text.textContent = address
      infowincontent.appendChild(text);
      var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        label: icon.label
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      markerCluster.addMarker(marker);
    });
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
<script async defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markerclustererplus/2.1.4/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```