# Marker Cluster for data from MYSQL DB - Google Maps API

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, markerclusterer

I have tried implementing a marker cluster into my code from the Google Developers Documentation but no joy so far. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Here is the snippet of code from my .JS file paying attention to the function showAllCustomers(allData) where I want to implement the Marker Clusterer:

```
var map;
var geocoder;

//Code to load the map with center point of Monterey MA
function initMap() {
    var monterey = {lat: 42.181613, lng: -73.215013};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: monterey,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        labels: true,
    });

    //collect customer data and geocoder object - declare geocoder as global
    var cusdata = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').innerHTML);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
    codeAddress(cusdata);

    var allData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('allData').innerHTML);
    showAllCustomers(allData)

    var searchData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('searchData').innerHTML);
    showSearchedCustomer(searchData)
    
}

function showAllCustomers(allData) {
    //declare info window variable outside of loop to allow to clear when selecting other markers
    var infoWind = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(allData, function(data){
        var content = document.createElement('div');
        var strong = document.createElement('strong');
        
        strong.textContent = [data.lastName + ' ' + data.physicalAddress];
        content.appendChild(strong);

        //add image to infowindow - you are also able to add image path to mysql and then append dynamically
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = 'images/santahat.png';
        img.style.width = '50px';
        content.appendChild(img);

        //Create markers for customer locations and customize
        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude),
          map: map,
          icon: iconBase + 'homegardenbusiness.png'
        });
        

        // Add event listener to open info window and show customer name
        marker.addListener('mouseover', function(){
            infoWind.setContent(content);
            infoWind.open(map, marker);
        
        //add event listener to zoom in to clicked customer
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                map.panTo(this.getPosition());
                map.setZoom(20);
                });  
        
        });
    }) 
}
```

Here is my attempt to add the MarkerClusterer (code same as previous up to this point):

```
//Create markers for customer locations and customize
        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude),
          map: map,
          icon: iconBase + 'homegardenbusiness.png'
        });
        
        //create marker clusterer to group data
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
      imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
    });

        // Add event listener to open info window and show customer name
        marker.addListener('mouseover', function(){
            infoWind.setContent(content);
            infoWind.open(map, marker);
        
        //add event listener to zoom in to clicked customer
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                map.panTo(this.getPosition());
                map.setZoom(20);
                });  
        });
        markerCluster.addMarker(marker);
    }) 
}
```

Comment: Where did you add the `MarkerClusterer`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Marker Clustering Not Showing using PHP and MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62124119/marker-clustering-not-showing-using-php-and-mysql)

Comment: possible duplicate of [marker cluster locations from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64530595/marker-cluster-locations-from-database)

Comment: If neither of the possible duplicates help, please search for other duplicates.  If you can't find one, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your best attempt add adding MarkerClustering to your code, preferably a working [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: Thank you - I have been using both of those duplicates plus others but to no success currently. I updated the question to provide my attempt also. I am missing something somewhere and appreciate the support! :)

Comment: Hard to tell where you are going wrong without a [mcve] ([StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) that exhibits the issue)

Comment: Sorry, just getting started and don't know the best way to make a minimal reproducible example as my app is connected through PHP and MYSQL. However I solved it with help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62124119/marker-clustering-not-showing-using-php-and-mysql as previously noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Functioning JS file:

```
var map;
var geocoder;

//Code to load the map with center point of Monterey MA
function initMap() {
    var monterey = {lat: 42.181613, lng: -73.215013};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: monterey,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        labels: true,
    });

    //collect customer data and geocoder object - declare geocoder as global
    var cusdata = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').innerHTML);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
    codeAddress(cusdata);

    var allData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('allData').innerHTML);
    showAllCustomers(allData);

    var searchData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('searchData').innerHTML);
    showSearchedCustomer(searchData)
    
}


function showAllCustomers(allData) {
    //declare info window variable outside of loop to allow to clear when selecting other markers
    var infoWind = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    //Create marker clusterer to group data
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
        imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
      });


    Array.prototype.forEach.call(allData, function(data){
        var content = document.createElement('div');
        var strong = document.createElement('strong');
        
        strong.textContent = [data.lastName + ' ' + data.physicalAddress];
        content.appendChild(strong);

        //add image to infowindow - you are also able to add image path to mysql and then append dynamically
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = 'images/santahat.png';
        img.style.width = '50px';
        content.appendChild(img);

        //Create markers for customer locations and customize
        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude),
          map: map,
          icon: iconBase + 'homegardenbusiness.png'
        });

        markerCluster.addMarker(marker);


        // Add event listener to open info window and show customer name
        marker.addListener('mouseover', function(){
            infoWind.setContent(content);
            infoWind.open(map, marker);
        
        //add event listener to zoom in to clicked customer
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                map.panTo(this.getPosition());
                map.setZoom(20);
                });  
        });
    }) 

}

//google maps geocoding code for address to collect lat lng from customer addresses
function codeAddress(cusdata) {
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(cusdata, function(data){
        var address = data.lastName + ' ' + data.physicalAddress;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

//create object that collects the lat and lng data and pass function to update customers lat lng
            var points = {};
            points.id = data.id;
            points.latitude = map.getCenter().lat();
            points.longitude = map.getCenter().lng();
            updateCustomersWithLatLng(points);
        
        //add code to check the result status from geocode request and if we get an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error we try again after slight delay // Jay 20201208-1015
        } else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {    
            setTimeout(function() {
                codeAddress(cusdata);
            }, 100);
         } // else {
        //     alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason:" 
        //           + status);
        // } 
        });
    });
}

//create update customers function that updates db using ajax call
function updateCustomersWithLatLng(points) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"action.php",
        method:"post",
        data: points,
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res)
        }
    })
    
}



//When search customers is clicked create function to zoom in to the searched customer
function showSearchedCustomer(searchData) {

    // var searchedCus = { ? };
    // map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    //  zoom: 20,
    //  center: searchedCus,
    //   });

    //declare info window vairable outside of loop to allow to clear if selecting other markers
    var infoWind = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(searchData, function(data){
        var content = document.createElement('div');
        var strong = document.createElement('strong');
        
        strong.textContent = [data.lastName + ' ' + data.physicalAddress];
        content.appendChild(strong);

        //add image to infowindow - you are also able to add image path to mysql and then append dynamically
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = 'images/santahat.png';
        img.style.width = '50px';
        content.appendChild(img);

        //Create marker for searched customer location and customize
        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({   
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude),
          map: map,
          icon: iconBase + 'homegardenbusiness.png'
        });

        // Add event listner to open info window and show customer name
        marker.addListener('mouseover', function(){
            infoWind.setContent(content);
            infoWind.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
}
```